# How to get address from latitude and longitude android?

Tags: android, eclipse, geolocation

I have an application that will get the latitude and the longitude of the users location. What I need to know is how do I take the latitude and the longitude of the location and convert it into just the address of the user?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GeoCoding. Follow the instructions on [this link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android) where it says Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding

You can find code there that you can try it out on your own app (copy/paste)

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
     try {
         Geocoder geocoder;
         List<Address> addresses;
         geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);
         Toast.makeText(this, "before if",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         if (latitude != 0 || longitude != 0) {
             addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude ,
                     longitude, 1);
                     String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
         String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
         String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
          Log.d("TAG", "address = "+address+", city ="+city+", country = "+country );
         Toast.makeText(this, "address = "+address+", city ="+city+", country = "+country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         } 
         else {
             Toast.makeText(this, "latitude and longitude are null",
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

     }
```