# How to get address from latiude and longitude?

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the latitude and longitude on touch event in map in android.

I want to getting address on particular touch in map.

How do I do this?

Comment: Before ask the question only type this keyword "How to get address from latiude and longitude?" and you can easily got the result .

Comment: @R.J - no. The other question is "how to get latitude and longitude" and not "how to get adress from latitude and longitude.

Comment: @Jitendra   I am finding so much but not getting accurate result and confused ..thats the reason for asking que..i want simple demo only..

Comment: The other moderators havent also havent read the link - its not good

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062126/getting-address-of-a-location-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-android); [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude); [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894804/how-to-get-address-from-latitude-and-longitude-android). Could list more but stopped at three.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377948/how-can-i-get-lat-lng-of-two-points-train-station-on-google-maps/13378110#13378110

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google [geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) and from them you call [`getFromLocation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29) given latitude and longitude... but be aware that it may be not really accurate.